# Change title and colorbar text and tick colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to know how to change the color of the ticks in the colorbar and how to change the font color of the title and colorbar in a figure. For example, things obviously are visible in temp.png but not in temp2.png:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

fig = plt.figure()
data = np.clip(randn(250,250),-1,1)
cax = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.title('my random fig')
plt.colorbar()

# works fine
plt.savefig('temp.png')
# title and colorbar ticks and text hidden
plt.savefig('temp2.png', facecolor="black", edgecolor="none")
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest looking into this [older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485000/python-matplotlib-colorbar-setting-tick-formator-locator-changes-tick-labels).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**(Update: The information in this answer is outdated, please scroll below for other answers which is up to date and better suited to new version)**

This can be done by inspecting and setting properties for object handler in matplotlib.

I edited your code and put some explanation in comment:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

fig = plt.figure()
data = np.clip(randn(250,250),-1,1)
cax = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')

title_obj = plt.title('my random fig') #get the title property handler
plt.getp(title_obj)                    #print out the properties of title
plt.getp(title_obj, 'text')            #print out the 'text' property for title
plt.setp(title_obj, color='r')         #set the color of title to red

axes_obj = plt.getp(cax,'axes')                 #get the axes' property handler
ytl_obj = plt.getp(axes_obj, 'yticklabels')     #get the properties for 
                                                #  yticklabels
plt.getp(ytl_obj)                               #print out a list of properties
                                                #  for yticklabels
plt.setp(ytl_obj, color="r")                    #set the color of yticks to red

plt.setp(plt.getp(axes_obj, 'xticklabels'), color='r') #xticklabels: same

color_bar = plt.colorbar()                            #this one is a little bit
cbytick_obj = plt.getp(color_bar.ax.axes, 'yticklabels')                #tricky
plt.setp(cbytick_obj, color='r')

plt.savefig('temp.png')
plt.savefig('temp2.png', facecolor="black", edgecolor="none")
```

Comment: Just an addition to people using subplots. You can just assign colors to separate colorbar axes object as follows:

cb = fig.colorbar(im,ax=ax), 
cb.ax.tick_params(axis='y',colors='white')

Answer (score 51):

Previous answer didnt give what I wanted. 
This is how I did it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
data = np.clip(randn(250,250),-1,1)
data = np.ma.masked_where(data > 0.5, data)


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

im = ax1.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
cb = plt.colorbar(im)

fg_color = 'white'
bg_color = 'black'

# IMSHOW    
# set title plus title color
ax1.set_title('ax1 title', color=fg_color)

# set figure facecolor
ax1.patch.set_facecolor(bg_color)

# set tick and ticklabel color
im.axes.tick_params(color=fg_color, labelcolor=fg_color)

# set imshow outline
for spine in im.axes.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor(fg_color)    

# COLORBAR
# set colorbar label plus label color
cb.set_label('colorbar label', color=fg_color)

# set colorbar tick color
cb.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(color=fg_color)

# set colorbar edgecolor 
cb.outline.set_edgecolor(fg_color)

# set colorbar ticklabels
plt.setp(plt.getp(cb.ax.axes, 'yticklabels'), color=fg_color)

fig.patch.set_facecolor(bg_color)    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('save/to/pic.png', dpi=200, facecolor=bg_color)
```

[image: black on white imshow]

Comment: `cb.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(color=fg_color, labelcolor=fg_color)` sets both the tick and tick-label colors at the same time.

Answer (score 19):

While the other answers are surely correct, it seems this is easier being solved using either styles or specific `rcParams`, or using the `tick_params` function

### Styles

Matplotlib provides a `dark_background` style. You may use it e.g. via `plt.style.use("dark_background")`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use("dark_background")

fig = plt.figure()
data = np.clip(np.random.randn(150,150),-1,1)
plt.imshow(data)
plt.title('my random fig')
plt.colorbar()  

plt.savefig('temp2.png', facecolor="black", edgecolor="none")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you need to create the same figure with and without black background styles may be used in a context.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_plot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    data = np.clip(np.random.randn(150,150),-1,1)
    plt.imshow(data)
    plt.title('my random fig')
    plt.colorbar()
    return fig

# create white background plot
create_plot()
plt.savefig('white_bg.png')

with plt.style.context("dark_background"):
    create_plot()
    plt.savefig('dark_bg.png', facecolor="black", edgecolor="none")
```

Read more about this in the [Customizing matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) tutorial.

### Specific rcParams

You may individually set the required [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams) that compose a style where needed in your script.

E.g. to make any text blue and yticks red:

```
params = {"text.color" : "blue",
          "xtick.color" : "crimson",
          "ytick.color" : "crimson"}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

This will automatically also colorize the tickmarks.

[image]

### Customizing ticks and labels

You may also customize the objects in the plot individually. For ticks and ticklabels there is a [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) method. E.g. to only make the ticks of the colorbar red,

```
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.tick_params(color="red", width=5, length=10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Based on previous answer I added two lines to set the colorbar's box color and colorbar's ticks color:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

fig = plt.figure()
data = np.clip(randn(250,250),-1,1)
cax = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')

title_obj = plt.title('my random fig') #get the title property handler
plt.setp(title_obj, color='w')         #set the color of title to white

axes_obj = plt.getp(cax,'axes')                        #get the axes' property handler
plt.setp(plt.getp(axes_obj, 'yticklabels'), color='w') #set yticklabels color
plt.setp(plt.getp(axes_obj, 'xticklabels'), color='w') #set xticklabels color

color_bar = plt.colorbar()                            
plt.setp(plt.getp(color_bar.ax.axes, 'yticklabels'), color='w') # set colorbar  
                                                                # yticklabels color
##### two new lines ####
color_bar.outline.set_color('w')                   #set colorbar box color
color_bar.ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(color='w')      #set colorbar ticks color 
##### two new lines ####

plt.setp(cbytick_obj, color='r')
plt.savefig('temp.png')
plt.savefig('temp3.png', facecolor="black", edgecolor="none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can change the tick labels with:

```
cax = plt.imshow(data)
cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', alpha=0.8, label ='my label',
                    fraction=0.075, pad=0.07, extend='max')
#get the ticks and transform it to list, if you want to add strings.
cbt = cbar.get_ticks().tolist() 
#edit the new list of ticks, for instance the firs element
cbt[0]='$no$ $data$'
# then, apply the changes on the actual colorbar
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(cbt)
```