# Set title color in stylesheet

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am setting a custom stylesheet in mpl. I found and modified some example settings online:

```
axes.titlesize  : 18
axes.labelsize  : large
axes.labelcolor : ffffff
```

I also want to change the font color of the title. From these settings, `axes.titlecolor` seemed like a good guess, but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @TheChymera Both answers below are correct. What else would you like to know?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Neither answer answers the question ("set title in stylesheet"). What I would like to know is how the title color can specifically be set via the style sheet.

Comment: @TheChymera From both answers you can see that setting the title color alone via the style sheet is not possible. I don't quite see how a new answer, saying yet another time that it is impossible would help here.

Comment: Maybe it's become possible in the 2 years which have since passed, or maybe one can hack it. The most obvious hack, defining a custom style sheet parameter and then reading it out with `rcParams` fails. But maybe something else doesn't. It's ok if you don't have an answer, I'm just thinking maybe somebody does.

Comment: @TheChymera You cannot simply put a new parameter into the style sheet.  This involves changing the source of the default rc Params and the source of the `set_title` method of the axes base class. If someone had done that work, he would have provided that as a pull request to the library. If you are willing to do that work, feel free to do the pull request yourself. If you want to inform the matplotlib development team of your wish to have such a parameter you can also create a wish list issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

Try using

```
# Sets title color
text.color = 'your_color'

# Sets other chart attribute colors
xtick.color = 'your_color'
ytick.color = 'your_color'
axes.labelcolor = 'your_color'
```

Printing out **mpl.rcParams.keys()** gives you a list of attributes that you can adjust.

Example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['text.color'] = 'w'
mpl.rcParams['xtick.color'] = 'w'
mpl.rcParams['ytick.color'] = 'w'
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelcolor'] = 'w'
```

Source:
https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Answer (score 5):

I am not completely familiar with how the Mpl stylesheets are actually implemented but my guess is that they are just pre-edited mpl rc files.

If they are indeed mpl rc files then based on reading through my current rc file there is no attribute in the 'Axes' for the color of the title.

My work around for adding stylistic functionality that may or may not be implemented in the rc files is do do something like:

```
using_custom_style = true
plt.use('my_style')
...
if using_custom_style:
    ax.set_title('my title', color=my_color_of_choice)
else:
    ax.set_title('my_title')  # this doesn't specify a color so it will just use whatever default vaule mpl knows to use
```

Its not the best workaround since it adds a lot of clutter o the code but it the only thing I have found to work when I can't figure out where the default setting is actually stored in the mpl param files or stylesheets.

analyzing the mpl rc file if you run something like 'grep title matplotlibrc' it spits out the only instances it finds the word title in the file:

# special text sizes tick labels, axes, labels, title, etc, see the rc

#axes.titlesize      : large   # fontsize of the axes title

so there doesn't seem to be a default color setting for the title - or rather if tis there its called something else that isn't directly obvious

'grep color matplotlibrc' outputs all instances of the word color in the rc file

Again there doesn't seem to be anything directly related to title colors or even default text color.

Looking a little closer at the Mpl API, axes.set_title() takes kwargs like color=, that are just labeled as valid Text properties.

http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text lists valid Text properties. For color all it says is 'any matplotlib color'

I'd imagine somewhere in the mpl source code there's a line that handles what to do when no color kwarg is specified for a given Text object. Somewhere there's a default color which I think is probably just 'k'. It isn't clear to me at this time, however, how to change that setting.

Sorry for the long discourse, hope this helps some.

Answer (score 2):

May be bit later answer but anyway )
 If you want to change default title color you could set text.color property in matplotrc file (default is black). Of course it will change colors of all your text outputs.

Answer (score -1):

This may work [(Refrenced From Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662995/matplotlib-change-title-and-colorbar-text-and-tick-colors/9666308)

```
title_obj = plt.title('my random fig') 
plt.getp(title_obj)                    
plt.getp(title_obj, 'text')            
plt.setp(title_obj, color='r')    #Sets it to the color red
```