# Any way to change the colour of a legend on a geopandas map?

Tags: python, visualization, geopandas

I have created the attached data visualisation using geopandas. When I save this as a png the background becomes black (in the attached picture the background is not black) and therefore the scale on the legend becomes invisible. Is there any way to change the colour of the legend?

nothing I have tried was successful

this is the code I used to create the visualisation:

```
#Creating Visualisation
worldmap = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
merged_df = worldmap.merge(finalDF, left_on='continent', 
right_on='Continent')
vmin, vmax = merged_df['NumberTourists'].min(), 
merged_df['NumberTourists'].max()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 12))
merged_df.plot(column='NumberTourists', cmap='Blues', linewidth=0.8, 
ax=ax, edgecolor='0.1', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, legend=True)



ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('A visualisation of the number of international \n tourists 
to visit each continent in 2018', fontsize = 20, color = 'white')

plt.show()
```

[image: 1]

Comment: I assume xour backend is `matplotlib`. So does this answer your question? [matplotlib: change title and colorbar text and tick colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662995/matplotlib-change-title-and-colorbar-text-and-tick-colors)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the error with the code you've given. A simple example would be:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

worldmap = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 12))
worldmap.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, cmap='Blues', legend=True)

# plt.show()
plt.savefig('tmp.png')
```

However, note that if `plt.show()` is *uncommented*, the png file is blank. Perhaps this is your issue?