# how to draw a colorbar with a white boundary

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

usually, when uses `fig.colorbar()`,it output like this[image]

but when I need to draw a colorbar inside a figure, I want a colorbar with a white boundary.

how can I do that? I cant find any example like this.[image]

thanks for any help

==========solution=============

```
cb.ax.spines[:].set_color('white') #makes the boundary white
cb.ax.tick_params(direction='out', colors='white') #makes ticks and labels white
```

Comment: And this: [Change title and colorbar text and tick colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42020486/12131013)