# Prevent scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scientific-notation

I have the following code:

```
plt.plot(range(2003,2012,1),range(200300,201200,100))
# several solutions from other questions have not worked, including
# plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(-1000000,1000000))
# ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.show()
```

which produces the following plot:

[image: plot]

How do I prevent scientific notation here? [Is ticklabel_format broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18209462/7758804) does not resolve the issue of actually removing the offset.

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(1e6, 3 * 1e7, 1e6))
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 243, accepted):

In your case, you're actually wanting to disable the offset.  Using scientific notation is a separate setting from showing things in terms of an offset value.

However, `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` should have worked (though you've listed it as one of the things that didn't).

For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(2003,2012,1),range(200300,201200,100))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to disable both the offset and scientific notaion, you'd use `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')`.

---

### Difference between "offset" and "scientific notation"

In matplotlib axis formatting, "scientific notation" refers to a *multiplier* for the numbers show, while the "offset" is a separate term that is *added*.

Consider this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1000, 1001, 100)
y = np.linspace(1e-9, 1e9, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The x-axis will have an offset (note the `+` sign) and the y-axis will use scientific notation (as a multiplier -- No plus sign).

[image]

We can disable either one separately.  The most convenient way is the `ax.ticklabel_format` method (or `plt.ticklabel_format`).

For example, if we call:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

We'll disable the scientific notation on the y-axis:

[image]

And if we call

```
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

We'll disable the offset on the x-axis, but leave the y-axis scientific notation untouched:

[image]

Finally, we can disable both through:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way to prevent scientific notation is to "widen" the interval where scientific notation is not used using the `scilimits=` parameter.

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(1e6, 3 * 1e7, 1e6))
plt.ticklabel_format(scilimits=(-5, 8))
```

[image: result1]

Here, scientific notation is used on an axis if the axis limit is less than 10^-5 or greater than 10^8.

By default, scientific notation is used for numbers [smaller than 10^-5 or greater than 10^6](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc#L386), so if the highest value of the ticks are in this interval, scientific notation is not used.

So the plot created by

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(50), np.logspace(0, 6));
plt.ylim((0, 1000000))
```

has scientific notation because 1000000=10^6 but the plot created by

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(50), np.logspace(0, 6));
plt.ylim((0, 999999));
```

does not because the y-limit (999999) is smaller than 10^6, the default limit.

This default limit can be changed by using the `scilimits=` parameter of `ticklabel_format()`; simply pass a tuple of the format: `(low, high)` where the upper limit of the ticks should be in the interval `(10^low, 10^high)`. For example, in the following code (a little extreme example), ticks are shown as full numbers because `np.logspace(0,100)[-1] < 10**101` is True.

```
plt.plot(np.logspace(0, 8), np.logspace(0, 100));
plt.ticklabel_format(scilimits=(0, 101))
```

[image: result2]

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this globally for all charts by

```py
    # Disable scientific notation on axes
    # by setting the threshold exponent very high
    matplotlib.rcParams["axes.formatter.limits"] = (-99, 99)
```