# Match 2 Graphs in an only image matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I´m trying to create some graphs from a dataframe I imported. The problem is I can create an only image with both graphs. I have this output:
[image]

And I´m looking for this Output:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('csv.csv', index_col = 'Totales', parse_dates=True)
df.head()
df['Subastas'].plot()
plt.title('Subastadas')
plt.xlabel('Fechas')
plt.ylabel('Cant de Subastadas')
plt.subplot()

df['Impresiones_exchange'].plot()
plt.title('Impresiones_exchange')
plt.xlabel('Fechas')
plt.ylabel('Cant de Impresiones_exchange')
plt.subplot()
plt.show()
```

CSV data:

```
Totales,Subastas,Impresiones_exchange,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,Fill_rate,ECPM_medio
Total_07/01/2017,1596260396,30453841,19742.04,3.024863813,0.733696498
Total_07/12/2017,1336604546,57558106,43474.29,9.368463445,0.656716233
Total_07/01/2018,1285872189,33518075,20614.4,4.872889166,0.678244085
```

Also, I would like to save the output in an xlsx file too!

Comment: Just change `plt.subplot()` to `plt.show()`.

Comment: I need to add both in the same fig not one for one @andrew_reece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.subplots()` to define two separate `Axes` objects, then use the `ax` argument of `df.plot()` to associate a plot to an axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(5,10))

df['Impresiones_exchange'].plot(ax=ax2)
ax1.set_title('Impresiones_exchange')
ax1.set_xlabel('Fechas')
ax1.set_ylabel('Cant de Impresiones_exchange')

df['Subastas'].plot(ax=ax1)
ax2.set_title('Subastadas')
ax2.set_xlabel('Fechas')
ax2.set_ylabel('Cant de Subastadas')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! And how can I change the positions for example one graph next to the other?

Comment: You're welcome.  To switch to side-by-side, change the row and column arguments in `plt.subplots()`, e.g. `plt.subplots(1,2)`.  Here are [several examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) from the pyplot docs.

Comment: Great! The last question...  I would like to have the same values I have in the data frame in the graphs right not 3.0....3.5.... ext

Comment: Do you mean you do not want the `1e9` and `1e7` indicated on the y-axis, but instead you want the full number like `1596260396`?

Comment: exactly!  That is

Comment: You can use `ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')`.  This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373421/2799941).

Comment: Thanks! I promiss this is the last question... if I would like to add a new graph on the image as ax3, what I need to change of your answer? Because I have an error that shows me "ax3 is not defined"

Comment: You need to add either a row or a column to the `subplots()` argument, like `f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1)`.  You should really read the examples and documentation, it's pretty useful.  There are also a lot of questions on StackOverflow that address these issues.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for all! You was very helpfull!!