# Use scientific notaion in Xaxis python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scientific-notation

I am trying to plot a dataset with some really small values on xaxis. I want to use scientific notation for all numbers on Xaxis. So I tried

```py
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
```

I get following errors:

```
xis.major.formatter.set_scientific(is_sci_style)
AttributeError: 'FuncFormatter' object has no attribute 'set_scientific'
```

can someone help me with that thank you very much.

my plot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To apply scientific notation you can employ a formatter function. See this post: [Can I turn of scientific notation in matplotlib bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165569/can-i-turn-of-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-bar-chart). I have applied the same logic as the user in the reference I have quoted to obtain the following simple example of a plot of a sine function with scientific notation on both axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

x = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
y = np.sin(x)

def scientific(x, pos):
    # x:  tick value
    # pos: tick position
    return '%.2E' % x

# create figure
plt.figure()
# plot sine
plt.plot(x,y)
# get current axes 
ax = plt.gca()
# initialize formatter
scientific_formatter = FuncFormatter(scientific)
# apply formatter on x and y axes
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(scientific_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(scientific_formatter)
# show plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey is there a way to use plt. instead of ax? Because my whole plot builts on plt.

Comment: You could use `ax = plt.gca()` to get the axes of the current plot. See code edit.