# How to incerease deciamls of y-axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, line-plot

All,

My dataset looks like following. I am using `matplotlib` to plot my time series such that `years` are on X-axis and Values are on Y-axis. However, when I plot my timeseries, My plot's y-axis displays scale in `float` instead of the values present in values column. I am using below code to plot. Also, I am not sure why is there `le10` on top-left corner of the plot.What does that mean ? Any help is appreciated!

**Dput of Dataframe**

```
{'CA': {Timestamp('1996-01-01 00:00:00'): 2128525783, Timestamp('1997-01-01 00:00:00'): 2950158700, Timestamp('1998-01-01 00:00:00'): 3231415116, Timestamp('1999-01-01 00:00:00'): 3605984016, Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'): 4195195633, Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:00:00'): 4723575766, Timestamp('2002-01-01 00:00:00'): 5233311750, Timestamp('2003-01-01 00:00:00'): 5966029333, Timestamp('2004-01-01 00:00:00'): 7212890750, Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'): 8519315100, Timestamp('2006-01-01 00:00:00'): 8987150650, Timestamp('2007-01-01 00:00:00'): 8558910700, Timestamp('2008-01-01 00:00:00'): 7342483350, Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00'): 6458302766, Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): 6303777983, Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'): 5957249400, Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00'): 6104143350, Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'): 7155131550, Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'): 7963149150, Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 8684498300, Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 9306005400, Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): 10003836500, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 10758058400}, 'NY': {Timestamp('1996-01-01 00:00:00'): 1178951383, Timestamp('1997-01-01 00:00:00'): 1592659499, Timestamp('1998-01-01 00:00:00'): 1662480216, Timestamp('1999-01-01 00:00:00'): 1777152200, Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'): 1947991966, Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:00:00'): 2164930866, Timestamp('2002-01-01 00:00:00'): 2420673000, Timestamp('2003-01-01 00:00:00'): 2756014650, Timestamp('2004-01-01 00:00:00'): 3307459750, Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'): 3726598750, Timestamp('2006-01-01 00:00:00'): 3990157300, Timestamp('2007-01-01 00:00:00'): 3977352416, Timestamp('2008-01-01 00:00:00'): 3870185299, Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00'): 3672557716, Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): 3616196116, Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'): 3525280300, Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00'): 3478067800, Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'): 3581461850, Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'): 3849163950, Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 4108014800, Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 4317332000, Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): 4538948400, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 4732210500}, 'FL': {Timestamp('1996-01-01 00:00:00'): 741024600, Timestamp('1997-01-01 00:00:00'): 1013996791, Timestamp('1998-01-01 00:00:00'): 1060794383, Timestamp('1999-01-01 00:00:00'): 1131940750, Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'): 1237303491, Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:00:00'): 1385764183, Timestamp('2002-01-01 00:00:00'): 1539792833, Timestamp('2003-01-01 00:00:00'): 1735415641, Timestamp('2004-01-01 00:00:00'): 2044244558, Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'): 2618944516, Timestamp('2006-01-01 00:00:00'): 2992975350, Timestamp('2007-01-01 00:00:00'): 2805320266, Timestamp('2008-01-01 00:00:00'): 2323686316, Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00'): 1878694700, Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): 1720143883, Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'): 1605149400, Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00'): 1628281300, Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'): 1768421500, Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'): 1959453200, Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 2143067300, Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 2358050300, Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): 2561805800, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 2746945000}, 'NJ': {Timestamp('1996-01-01 00:00:00'): 790085150, Timestamp('1997-01-01 00:00:00'): 1067475300, Timestamp('1998-01-01 00:00:00'): 1112856950, Timestamp('1999-01-01 00:00:00'): 1192722750, Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'): 1320036200, Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:00:00'): 1476539450, Timestamp('2002-01-01 00:00:00'): 1668911150, Timestamp('2003-01-01 00:00:00'): 1909804250, Timestamp('2004-01-01 00:00:00'): 2177337200, Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'): 2505342850, Timestamp('2006-01-01 00:00:00'): 2717805700, Timestamp('2007-01-01 00:00:00'): 2673733700, Timestamp('2008-01-01 00:00:00'): 2510177200, Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00'): 2297581100, Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): 2203120050, Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'): 2082609500, Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00'): 2004990200, Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'): 2042930100, Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'): 2113834900, Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 2137643100, Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 2179547500, Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): 2294435800, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 2424469100}, 'MA': {Timestamp('1996-01-01 00:00:00'): 603259700, Timestamp('1997-01-01 00:00:00'): 839255500, Timestamp('1998-01-01 00:00:00'): 910597850, Timestamp('1999-01-01 00:00:00'): 1017705350, Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'): 1170870700, Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:00:00'): 1343893550, Timestamp('2002-01-01 00:00:00'): 1517271950, Timestamp('2003-01-01 00:00:00'): 1683243700, Timestamp('2004-01-01 00:00:00'): 1844111700, Timestamp('2005-01-01 00:00:00'): 1983363350, Timestamp('2006-01-01 00:00:00'): 1958119750, Timestamp('2007-01-01 00:00:00'): 1881206300, Timestamp('2008-01-01 00:00:00'): 1762022050, Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00'): 1686196400, Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): 1676366200, Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00'): 1620330100, Timestamp('2012-01-01 00:00:00'): 1618160400, Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'): 1705540950, Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'): 1813555250, Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 1926733100, Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 2031505800, Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): 2185503500, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 2327396600}}
```

**My code for line Chart**

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=10,5
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']='white'
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor']='white'
df.plot()
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(frameon=True)
plt.ylabel('Prices ')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You want to use the "plain" format, `plt.gca().ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain')` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373421/4124317).

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks! How about X-axis ?. I would like to include all dates.

Comment: That's a totally different question. I wouldn't recommend doing so, because then labels will overlap. But of course you can. You should be able to find an answer somewhere, and if no, please do ask a new question.

Comment: Great. Thank you again for your time and efforts!