# Why is the y-axis of my plot being scaled by a difference?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot data, and I'm seeing the following (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

The y-axis is, presumably, being multiplied by 1e-10 - 6.767403e-3. I've seen the y axis get multiplied by a factor before, which makes sense, but I'm not sure why there's a difference now. What does that mean, and why does it happen?

Comment: The data is multiplied by 10^(-10) and offset by 6.7*10^(-3). This happens because your data is squeezed in a relatively small range, far away from 0. The multiplication and offset allow to still put nice numbers on the axes in such case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Is it possible for me to remove this offset in order to be able to accurately tell what my data is showing?

Comment: Yes, as seen  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot