# Remove natural log scale from Seaborn Bar Plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I was trying to have some plot in seaborn and so far here is the code

```
# Plot the results
# Bar plot of Yearly CBM
historica_cost = sns.barplot(
    x = harvest_yearly_cost.year,
    y = harvest_yearly_cost.harvest_cost,).set_title('Historical Yearly Harvest Cost')

historica_cost.figure.savefig('./export/yealy_felling_cbm.png')
```

The output is as shown below
[bar plot with log scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u54wB.png)

How can i remove the log scale and have the origal numbers in the data which were in Millions

Comment: Your y axis is not in log scale. What you want is to format the y axis tick labels. The question linked in the previous comment should tell you how to do it.

Comment: Note that your plot is not logarithmically scaled. It is a normal linear scale. What you see it a factor in scientific notation. See [prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot)