# Use matplotlib.ticker.Locator to put ticks only if location is divisible by a given value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

For example I need to set a tick only if dividing by 9 gives a "nice" value (nice here has the same meaning as in https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html).

Accordingly any set of following ticks should be allowed.

- `[9, 18, 27]` allowed b/c dividing by 9 gives `[1, 2, 3]`
- `[27, 54, 81, 108]` allowed b/c dividing by 9 gives `[3, 6, 9, 12]`
- `[0.45, 0.9, 1.35]` allowed b/c dividing by 9 gives `[0.05, 0.1, 0.15]`

Note that I am not looking to set ticks at every multiple of 9, so `MultipleLocator` doesn't work here.

I also want the locator to automatically figure out "how many ticks" and "best tick interval" etc. Basically I need the functionality of `MaxNLocator` with my additional divisibility requirement.

Current best solution is `MaxNLocator` with the arguments `MaxNLocator('auto', steps=[9])`. But `MaxNLocator` explicitly adds `10` to the `steps` argument (see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L2058) so sometimes I get tick values like `[1000, 2000, 3000]` which aren't acceptable. (1000 is not a multiple of 9, see the example 1,2,3 below)

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** See below for some nice vs. not nice examples.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def draw(name, xmax, steps, verdict):
    x = np.linspace(0, xmax)
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    plt.gca().set_xlim([0, xmax])
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator('auto', steps=steps))

    vd = 'NICE!!!\n' if verdict else 'NOT nice!\n'
    print(name, plt.gca().get_xticks()/9, '>>', vd)


draw('example 1', 64, [9], True)
draw('example 2', 7.2, [9], True)
draw('example 3', 90000, [9], False)
draw('example 4', 9, [1, 3, 9], False)
draw('example 5', 90, [1.8, 4.5, 9], False)
```

Output:

```
example 1 [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8.] >> NICE!!!

example 2 [0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8] >> NICE!!!

example 3 [0. 1111.11111111  2222.22222222  3333.33333333
  4444.44444444  5555.55555556  6666.66666667  7777.77777778
  8888.88888889 10000.] >> NOT nice!

example 4 [0. 0.11111111 0.22222222 0.33333333 0.44444444 0.55555556
 0.66666667 0.77777778 0.88888889 1.] >> NOT nice!

example 5 [ 0.  1.11111111  2.22222222  3.33333333  4.44444444  5.55555556
  6.66666667  7.77777778  8.88888889 10.] >> NOT nice!
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a `steps=` argument to MaxNLocator. These steps need to be between 1 and 10. In your case you could put there the values you like to be used as multiplicator. For example `[1.8, 4.5, 9]`.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 999)
y = np.sin(x/100)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(steps=[1.8, 4.5, 9]))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(steps=[1.8, 4.5, 9]))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks! But as per my requirement 3, 6, 12 shouldn't appear b/c they don't give nice ticks. See example 4 in my updated question.

Comment: I see you have updated the answer. Again I can find some x limit that breaks the solution. See newly added example 5. I think MaxNLocator can't deliver as long as it manually adds 10 to the steps argument (see the second link in my question). Do you know why MaxNLocator explicitly adds 10?

Comment: Good point. Just tested this by removing 'auto'. It works sometimes but doesn't work with for example xmax=99, steps=[1.8, 4.5, 9].

Comment: `draw('example 6', 999, [1.8, 4.5, 9], True)` gives `[  0.  20.  40.  60.  80. 100. 120.]` to me. What wrong with that?

Comment: Strange, here's what I got for `for i in range(1,100): draw(str(i), i, [1.8, 4.5, 9], True)` with `MaxNLocator(steps=steps)`. Ignore the NICE and NOT NICE in the output:
https://pastebin.com/1aqRxdEs. 
So still doesn't work for `i` = 1, 10, 91-99. Can you run a range and see what happens?

Comment: Indeed, for some values, the output is `[0,1,2,...]` or `[0,10,20,..]` instead of the multiples of 9. I think this is a bug in the implementation of the `steps` option of `MaxNLocator`. It seems to happen every time the numbers `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` (or a power of 10 multiple) are a perfect fit.

Comment: I think the reason for this is mpl manually adds `10` to `steps` (ticker.py#L2058). So no matter what `steps` you pass into the locator `10` is always there and sometimes we get multiples of `10`, not `9`. The question is why does it do that? I don't know if there is a fundamental reason for this. Currently my hack is to manually set the `_extended_steps` variable in `MaxNLocator`.

Comment: You could rise an issue in matplotlib's github to at least get an option to leave 10 out of the `steps`. With *usual use case* I meant most people do want 10 inside the steps, and seemingly nobody has raised the question before. It could also be interesting to have `'auto'` work nicely together with these steps. There seems to be an old discussion [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7578) insisting on 1 and 10 being part of steps, and that older versions could fall in an infinite loop.

Comment: Also note that matplotlib jumps to an [offset notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot), for example if the x-range would go from `1000000` to `1000010`. This behavior could be complicated to combine with your desire of leaving out 1 and 10.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks for links. I am gong to keep this SO post as an open question for now.