# When plotting a pandas dataframe, the y-axis values are not displayed correctly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe (see link for image) and I've listed the info on the data frame.  I use the `pivot_table` function to sum the total number of births for each year. The issue is that when I try to plot the dataframe, the y-axis values range from `0` to `2.0` instead of the minimum and maximum values from the `M` and `F` columns.

To verify that it's not my environment, I created a simple dataframe, with just a few values and plot the line graph for that dataframe and it works as expected.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  Attempting to set the values using `ylim` or `yticks` is not working.  Ultimately, I will have to try other graphing utilities like matplotlib, but I'm curious as to why it's not working for such a simple dataframe and dataset.

Visit my github page for a working example <git@github.com:stevencorrea-chicago/stackoverflow_question.git>

[image: Dataframe]

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1690784 entries, 0 to 1690783
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count    Dtype 
---  ------  --------------    ----- 
 0   name    1690784 non-null  object
 1   sex     1690784 non-null  object
 2   births  1690784 non-null  int64 
 3   year    1690784 non-null  Int64 
dtypes: Int64(1), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 53.2+ MB
```

```
new_df = df.pivot_table(values='births', index='year', columns='sex', aggfunc=sum)
new_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 131 entries, 1880 to 2010
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   F       131 non-null    int64
 1   M       131 non-null    int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 3.1+ KB
```

[image: plot graphic for dataframe of pivot_table]

[image: Test dataframe and plot to show it works for much smaller dataframe]

Comment: Do not include data as an image. Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block or include synthetic data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Just fyi, yaxis doesn't go from 0 to 2, it's from 0 to 2.000.000 (there's a 1e6 next to yaxis, which means the values have to be multiplied by 10^6)

Comment: _Ultimately, I will have to try other graphing utilities like matplotlib_ this is using matplotlib. Include the code used to generate the first graph.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the y-axis is properly displayed. The sum for each year is in the millions.

Comment: [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: The comments have all been helpful. I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm learning the proper protocol for posting.

Comment: No worries, welcome to stackoverflow. If you have yet to do so, you could check out the site tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and 'How to Ask A Good Question': https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to familiarize with the site :)