# How to control the format of Matplotlib axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, matplotlib, axes

I am plotting geographic coordinates with Matplotlib and I want to force the axes to remain in the correct format instead of changing to scientific notation.

```
Data set coordinate format is:
x - 123456.123
y - 1234567.123
```

I don't need to keep the 3 decimal places if that helps.

Depending on how I resize the plot (drag the corner of the figure), it will often convert to scientific notation as the image shows (only one has changed in this image).

```
x - 1.234 1e6
y - 1.234 1e7
```

[image: Output map]

How can I force the axes to remain in 'normal' numbers?

The code for the plot is:

```
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,4))
    ax.scatter(sx,sy,s=2)
    ax.set_title('Map view of Trace locations')
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot