# Why is my distribution so strange in sns.boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

So i am trying to plot the distribution of my dataset, in order to find outliers using IQR.
However instead of displaying say (0 to 100000) the x axis scale is from 0 to 1, with almost all of the data clustered at 0, despite me having removed all null values. Could someone please explain where i have gone wrong and why the scale of my plot is only 0 to 1, below is the full code and an image of the plot.
The dataset has an IQR of 51770 so this scale of 0 - 1 cannot be right, or is a reduced version.

This also is not particularly useful or correct as instead of having an outlier list with say 10 IQR values there are too many to count.

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action = 'ignore', category = FutureWarning)

from IPython.display import display

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

invest_2019 = pd.read_csv("Investment_2019.csv")
invest_2019['Investment2019'][invest_2019['Investment2019'] < 0] = np.nan
invest_2019.dropna(inplace = True)

invest_2019.isnull().sum()

x = invest_2019['Investment2019']

# Detect Outliers:
sns.boxplot(x)  # initial plot
plt.show()

Q1 = x.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = x.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
print("IQR: ", IQR, "\n")

b = Q1 - (1.5*IQR)
t = Q3 + (1.5*IQR)
r = t-b
print("bottom shadow:", b)
print("top shadow", t)
print("range: ", r, "\n")

outlie = x[(x < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (x > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))]

outlie
```

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMIde.png)

Comment: Did you notice the `1e7` in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Yes i did, is it some sort of notation for large numbers?

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373421/9245853).

Comment: I see that i can supress it, thank you

Comment: Would you be so kind as to share how i can supress this via seaborn as this appears to be for matplotlib and i am unsure of how to do it.

Comment: Create your axes with matplotlib and pass it to `sns.boxplot`, which has an `ax` parameter.

Comment: Apologies but i have very limited experience with plotting so i am still unsure as to how to do this. Thank you though!

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, `sns.boxplot(x, ax=ax)`.

Comment: or `ax = sns.boxplot(x) ` and `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')`. You can further add `ax.set_xlim(xmax=2000000)` to hide the largest of the outliers (they then will be out of view).

Comment: Yes all sorted thanks to both of you!