# How do I show the actual number in millions?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

### MY CODE:

```
***#Bar Graph 
plt.figure(figsize=(19,10))
sns.barplot(x="STATE_NAME", y="pop", data= sum_of_pop,ci = None)
plt.title(elevation+"_"+pop+"_"+str(year)+'_'+lecz)
plt.xticks(rotation=35,fontsize=11)
plt.yticks(fontsize=11)
plt.xlabel("State Name",fontsize=11) 
plt.ylabel("\nPopulation\n",fontsize=11) 
#plt.show()
plt.savefig(r"C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\lecz_graph\\bar_graph\\"+elevation+"_"+pop+"_"+str(year)+"_"+lecz+".png", dpi=400)***
```

---

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 0):

You can `format` the `y-axis tick` using `Formatter`. Basically It's a function that lets you transform the tick label to be an integer, a fixed-place decimal, or lots of other things.

Refer below example.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, FormatStrFormatter

ax = plt.axes(xscale='log', yscale='log')
ax.set_xlim(10e3,100e5)
ax.set_ylim(10e4,10e5)
ax.grid()
```

this will generate normal plot as shown below.

[image: Actual same data]

Now let's add `major` and `minor` formatter

```py
ax = plt.axes(xscale='log', yscale='log')
ax.set_xlim(10e3,100e5)
ax.set_ylim(10e4,10e5)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.3f")) # minor axis formattter
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.3f")) # major axis formattter
ax.grid()
```

**Output Image:** Please notice the `Y-axis ticks`. You can also do this for `x-axis ticks` if you want.

[image: OutputImage]