# Matplotlib not plotting several points on horizontal barplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graphing

Matplotlib appears to not be plotting several points despite me changing the x-limit based on the inputted numbers I am trying to graph. (x-limit because this is a horizontal barplot).

Here is the code:

```
    low = min(df_grouped_underlying['Currency Exposure'].astype(float))
    high = max(df_grouped_underlying['Currency Exposure'].astype(float))
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.set_xlim([math.ceil(low-0.5*(high-low)), math.ceil(high+0.5*(high-low))])
    bar_1 = ax.barh(df_grouped_underlying.index, df_grouped_underlying['Currency Exposure'].astype(float), label='Currency Exposure')
    ax.set(title = 'Currency_Exposure_Underlying_Position',
       ylabel = 'Underlying Currency',
       xlabel = 'Exposure')
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
    plt.savefig('agg_exposure.png', bbox_inches='tight') 
    plt.show()
```

Here is the output:
[Output of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ev9.png)

Comment: @BigBen Unfortunately that didn't change anything within the output besides the tick mark format. I do like how it looks now, but still isn't correctly plotting the data

Comment: `ax.set(xscale='symlog')`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thank you so much! Can you post this as an answer so I can upvote and accept? Also, do you have any good resources for python/matplotlib? Best!

Comment: Glad that helped. I'm just going to close it as a duplicate

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney is there a way to remove scientific notation on the x axis after I use your line of code from above? I googled around but couldn't find a solution tbh. Thanks again.

Comment: See [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371674/7758804)