# How do I change le6 to 1000000 in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

[image]

I wish to change the yticks on the figure, mainly change the le6 labeled on the top to 1000000, 2000000, ... on the yaxis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before the plot commands:
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')