# problem with y ticks when using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am learning to use matplotlib with the book "**Python Crash Course**". After completely following the book's instructions to draw a graph, my graph and the book's graph look different in that the book's graph shows the y ticks fully but mine are shortened.

I'll attach the images of both graphs, Would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to get my graph to look like the book's.

My graph:

[image]

the book's graph:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the tick label format as scientific or plain as [cited here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 1000, 1)
y = np.power(x, 2)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ticklabel_format(style="plain") 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered on the site. You may what to see [how should duplicate questions be handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: @BigBen My bad, should I delete the answer?

Comment: I don't believe you can at this point, since it's been accepted. More just a thought going foward.

Comment: @BigBen oke, I'll be more careful next time