# How can I fix my python code using Matplotlib.pyplot to have the median line working correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

As it is now , my median line is showing but I am not so sure why the value of the median line displayed is not in correctly plotted on the y-axis. For example , my median is 1.4 and another box plot's median is 2.4. However , the median line for 2.4 is below the median line 1.4 so it is not ordered correctly as it should be higher than the previous median line.

[image]

Code:

```
boxplot1=plt.boxplot(data,labels=labelling,patch_artist=True,widths =  0.7)

boxplot1['boxes'][0].set_facecolor('cyan')
boxplot1['boxes'][1].set_facecolor('moccasin')  
boxplot1['boxes'][2].set_facecolor('turquoise')  
boxplot1['boxes'][3].set_facecolor('coral')
boxplot1['boxes'][4].set_facecolor('khaki') 



for line in boxplot1['medians']:

    x, y = line.get_xydata()[1]
    
    plt.text(x, y, '%.1f' % x,
         horizontalalignment='center') 

plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.text(x, y, '%.1f' % x,` shouldn't it be `plt.text(x, y, '%.1f' % y`?

Comment: Also note that your y-axis has a multiplication factor of `1e6` written at the top. If you write these values using `'%.1f'` you get a number similar to `123456.7`.

Comment: Do you know how to change y-axis value to non - exponential form?

Comment: @Mr.T Im sorry it was my first time asking a question. I will remember to do that next time thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373421/8881141).