# how to round off y-axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the graph in python. I want to roundoff the y-axis as the values are too larger

I tried this code

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=",")
plt.plot(df['No'], df['B'], marker='.',  color = 'green')
#plt.plot(df['No'], df['B'], marker='.', label='bb')
#plt.show()
plt.xlabel('No')
plt.ylabel('B')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 10+1, 2))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

my graph looks like this
[image]

how can I round off the y-axis

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "round off"? Do you want to use scientific notation, e.g., 2e5 or do you want to limit the maximum y-values?

Comment: @BanDoP exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 0):

Well, limiting the y-axis is done by `plt.ylim(0, 500000)` while changing the format can be done by this snippet, that I copied from somewhere some time ago:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

formatter1 = ScalarFormatter(useOffset=True)  
formatter1.set_powerlimits((-3, 3))  #  use scientific notation below 10^-3 and above 10^3
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter1)
```