# Issue with pyplot displaying the exact values of my data set

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

Here I am using pyplot to plot a 2D data set. A sample of y values are as follows:

[-1373.2462605,
-1373.24749231,
-1373.24790325,
-1373.24830765,
-1373.24890634,
-1373.24956865,
-1373.25012217,
-1373.25048158,
-1373.2506672,
-1373.2507486,
-1373.25079881,
-1373.25085977,
-1373.25094396,
-1373.25104361,
-1373.25114657,]

How do I prevent the plot from doing this weird thing where it states -1.3732e3 at the top?

[image]

The code used is as follows:

```
plt.plot(ecutwfc1, energy1)
font1 = {'family':'serif','color':'Black','size':12}
font2 = {'family':'serif','color':'Black','size':11}
plt.title("Ta2C - varying K.E cut off",fontdict = font1)
plt.xlabel("ecutwfc Ry",fontdict = font2)
plt.ylabel("Total Energy Ry",fontdict = font2)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Ta2C_CT_ecut.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373421/12580704))

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```