# Weird plot when plotting a nearly-constant list

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot this simple list called `energy_list` which looks like

```
energy_list = [-31.996423234368955, -32.00000000000772, -32.000000000000014, -31.99500000000001,
               -31.999999999999982, -32.0, -32.000000000000014, -32.00000000000001,
               -32.00000000000002, -32.00000000000001, -32.0, -31.99500000000002,
               -32.000000000000014, -32.0, -32.000000000000036, -32.00000000000001, -32.0,
               -32.00000000000001, -32.000000000023576, -32.000000000000014, -32.00000000000007,
               -31.999999999999996, -32.0, -32.00000000000002, -32.0, -31.999999999999993,
               -32.00000000000001, -32.000000000000014, -31.995000000000005, -32.000000000429914,
               -32.0, -32.0, -31.99999999999999, -31.999999999999996, -31.99999999999999, -32.0,
               -31.999999999999996, -32.0, -32.00000000000001, -32.00000000000007,
               -32.00000000000001, -31.999999999999996, -32.000000000000014, -31.995000000000005,
               -32.00000000000001, -32.000000000000014, -32.00000000000001, -32.00000000000001,
               -32.000000000000014, -32.00000000000565]
```

The plot should be a somewhat constant function. But when I plot it using `plt.plot(energy_list)` I get this annoying plot:

[image]

What on earth is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the little number in the top-left corner of the axes that says `-3.199e1`? This tells you the `y` value of the line is whatever is specified by the apparent y coordinate, plus `-31.99`. Since you did not specify the limits of the y axis, matplotlib calculated them automatically from the data, and zoomed in to this level, your data is *not* constant.

Your data looks like a constant line when you specify the y limits:

```
plt.plot(energy_list)
plt.ylim(-34, -30)
```

[image]

If you'd rather not hardcode these limits, you can just add/subtract a set value to the max/min of the data:

```
upper_lim = round(max(energy_list) + 2)
lower_lim = round(min(energy_list) - 2)
plt.ylim(lower_lim, upper_lim)
```