# How to interpret the xaxis values of a density histogram when there's an offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a list of 100000 values, all are around 299800 as shown below.

```
values = [299850.3 299856.4 299855.9 ... 299843.7 299847.2 299860.9]
```

When I plot a Probability Density Function (PDF) of these values using `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`, I am getting the plot whose X-axis and Y-Axis values are confusing. I expect the X-axis values to be binned around 299800 and Y-axis values be the probability of those binned values happening. How to interpret this graph values correctly, appreciate any comments.

```
plt.hist(values,density=True, bins=30)
plt.xlabel("Values")
plt.ylabel('PDF')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The x value 30 means 30 + 2.998E5; the x value 40 means 40 + 2.998E5 and so on...

Comment: I suggest using [Prevent scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371674/7758804), if it's confusing.

Comment: @Joao_PS, Simple explanation. I don't know why it did not strike me..:)