# Can I display pixel value of picture without scientific notation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example, I have a numpy array and I use matplotlib to show it as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.array([[12,230],[1322,2122]])
tmp = plt.imshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

But I want to show complete number like `2122` without scientific notation `2.12e+03` in the lower right corner. Some ways from [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot) and [Is ticklabel_format broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209462/is-ticklabel-format-broken) don't work.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the cursor data on the plot's navigation bar, replace the AxesImage's `format_cursor_data` with the one we intend to use. In this case, we use `str` function to convert numeral into string without scientific notation.

First we define our custom `format_cursor_data` function:

```
def format_cursor_data(data):
    return "[" + str(data) + "]"
```

And then replace the AxesImage's `format_cursor_data` function with our own:

```
tmp.format_cursor_data = format_cursor_data
```

Hence, the full script will look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.array([[12,230],[1322,2122]])
tmp = plt.imshow(img,cmap=plt.cm.jet)

def format_cursor_data(data):
    return "[" + str(data) + "]"

tmp.format_cursor_data = format_cursor_data

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]