# How to correctly name the "X" axis in Matplotlib for long integer values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following result table.

[image]

When I try to plot the data, it seems that the "X" axis values are converted to "e scale". Is there a fix to this.
[image]

I use following code to create the plot.

```
fig = plt.figure()#figsize=(11,8)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(bulk_ingest_data['initial_records'][0:5], bulk_ingest_data['hf_gen(s)'][0:5], color='r', marker='o', label='LAS data in text form') #500
ax1.plot(bulk_ingest_data['initial_records'][5:10], bulk_ingest_data['hf_gen(s)'][5:10], color='b', marker='o', label='Binary encoded LAS points') #200
#ax1.plot(data['clients'][13:17], data['total'][13:17],  color='r', marker='o', label='2636407 points') #50

#ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0)
# loc=1,bbox_to_anchor=(0.6,0.5)
fig.suptitle('')#, fontsize=20
plt.xlabel('Number of records ingested)')# fontsize=18
plt.ylabel('HFile generation time(s)')# fontsize=16
#HFile generation time for LAS data in text format and LAS data in sequence format


handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
lgd = ax1.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.15,1))
ax1.grid('on'
```

)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)
[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: How do you want the labels formatted?

Comment: @wwii, I want the labels to be in their integer form. not in the *e-scale* form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot), and [Is ticklabel_format broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209462/is-ticklabel-format-broken)

Comment: Appreciate. Thanks a lot!. It worked. I'll mark it as the accepted answer if you decide to make a separate answer :)