# Why is Matplotlib Bar plot cutting out high values even if Y lim is specified?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

### I want to plot a bar plot with this code:

```
graph_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols = ['X', 'Y'])

ax = graph_data.plot.bar(x='X', y='Y', figsize=(15, 5))
plt.title("X [-]")
plt.ylim([0,1120394]) #Max value from the dataset
plt.show()
```

- I read the data from `.csv` file
- Then I specify the `ylim` to `[0,1120394]` (which is the highest value in the dataset).
- And plot the bar plot

### The output plot:

[image]

- As you can see the bars `S29`, `S30`, `S33`, `S34` and `S37` are cut.
- I want to plot a bar plot that will show the full length of each column.
- Also I would love if `Y` axis could show me the actual values? Why is it showing `1e6`?

---

### Edit

If I use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371674/11101156) (and other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209462/is-ticklabel-format-broken) referring to this) pointed out by the comments I end up with this code:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') #To set off scientific notation
...
or
...
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Both lines get me those errors:

```
AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter
```

Comment: To show "actual values":  [prevent scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot).  About the bar's possible cut off: maybe they just touch the top.  Default the ylims woud be set to `max(y)*1.05`

Comment: @JohanC Hi and thank you for your comment! Unfortunately I tried those answers and they didn't work - I edited my question.

Comment: How would I do that please? If you want you can post your answer to this question.

Comment: `ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain')`

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said you can post your answer and I can accept it :)