# In the graph, use the Python ML value in exp instead of an integer or float

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, graph, data-analysis

```
y_test=np.array(y_test)
y_pred=np.array(y_pred)
plt.scatter(y_test,y_pred,color='red')
plt.xlabel('Actual Values')
plt.ylabel('Prediction Values')
plt.title('Actual vs Predicted')
```

I have tried the above code and have got the below graph.

![enter image description here][1]

The graph axis values are coming in exp form. How to correct that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uFZj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ticklabel\_format broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209462/is-ticklabel-format-broken)

Comment: please share part of your dataset

Comment: @Mouse
I have tried the tick label format but there is no change in the graph
I have attached the new photo in the question

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly set the axis labels to the number format you need using scientific notation if you are not okay with the format provided by default. [Link here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html). A sample example is shown below. You will need to adjust `scilimits` to indicate how many digits you want to see in the plot.

```
x=[2000000, 4000000, 6000000, 8000000]
y=[2000000, 4000000, 6000000, 8000000]
plt.scatter(x, y, c='red')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(5,7))
plt.show()
```

[image]