# Matplotlib tick formatter for large numbers

Tags: matplotlib, axes, formatter, ticker, yticks

When I run this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.arange(1e6, 3 * 1e7, 1e6))
```

I get this plot [plot_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB5Av.png),

where the y-axis is a bit weird (there is a *1e7* on the top).

So, I am trying to fix this. I came up with a solution using *FuncFormatter*,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.arange(1e6, 3 * 1e7, 1e6))
def y_fmt(x, y):
    if x == 0:
        return r'$0$'
    
    r, p = "{:.1e}".format(x).split('e+')
    r = r[:-2] if r[-1] == '0' else r
    p = p[1:] if p[0] == '0' else p
    
    return r'${:}\times10^{:}$'.format(r, p)

plt.gca().get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(y_fmt))
```

here is the result [plot_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0note.png).

My question is, is there a better way of doing this, maybe using [LogFormatterSciNotation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterSciNotation)? Or is it possible to say *matplotlib* to not put *1e7* on the top?

UPDATE:

I didn’t know that there is such a thing as

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

but it seems that this is not doing anything for the data I used above (*np.arange(1e6, 3 * 1e7, 1e6)*). I don’t know if this is a bug or if there is something I don’t understand about this function...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ticklabel_format broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18209462/7758804) `plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)`

Comment: I didn’t know about this, but it seems that it is not working for my case.

Comment: Seems it needs to be `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')`

Comment: Nope, that’s not what I want. I want it in the scientific style (powers of 10).

Answer (score 0):

You may want `ScalarFormatter` and `ticklabel_format`. Some claimed you need both two of them, or just `ScalarFormatter` and don't need `ticklabel_format`. I'm not entirely sure about this behaviour. But it works.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(np.arange(1e6, 3 * 1e7, 1e6))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mt.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
ax.ticklabel_format(style="sci", axis="y", scilimits=(0,2))
```

[image: ex]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in your example, there is _x10^7_ on the top. I want it to be on the left with y-ticks.

Comment: @Arto I see. My bad. Then I don't come up with an easy way to do it. I would use `FuncFormatter` like you did.