# Cleanest way to hide every nth tick label in matplotlib colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The labels on my horizontal colorbar are too close together and I don't want to reduce text size further:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink=0.8, orientation='horizontal', extend='both', pad=0.02)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
```

[image: horizontal colorbar with bad labels]

I'd like to preserve all ticks, but remove every other label.

Most examples I've found pass a user-specified list of strings to cbar.set_ticklabels().  I'm looking for a general solution.

I played around with variations of

```
cbar.set_ticklabels(cbar.get_ticklabels()[::2])
```

and

```
cbar.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=4))
```

but I haven't found the magic combination.

I know there must be a clean way to do this using a locator object.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485000/python-matplotlib-colorbar-setting-tick-formator-locator-changes-tick-labels?rq=1 ?  The ticks on colorbar can be finicky (as there is a layer in there to make it easy to flip from a vertical to horizontal with out changing too much of your code (ideally just adding a kwarg))

Comment: Yeah.  That post was helpful, and I ran update_ticks() during my preliminary tests, but the final solution offered still involves user-defined lists for tick locs/labels.

Comment: In case someone wanted to use `pyplot` directly instead of `axes` object: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Answer (score 96, accepted):

For loop the ticklabels, and call `set_visible()`:

```
for label in cbar.ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Just as an alternate way of doing the exact same thing: You can do `plt.setp(cbar.ax.get_xticklabels()[::2], visible=False)`.  This is identical, of course, but it can be handy to at least know about `setp`. Then again, a for loop is clearer and instantly readable, while `setp` isn't clear unless you're familiar with matplotlib.

Comment: If your colorbar is oriented vertically, you will need to use `cbar.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()` instead

Comment: Also, you can of course use `get_xticklabels()[1::2]` to hide very other label. This will usually be necessary if the start of your axis does not coincide with a tick but you still want to keep the first (visible) tick visible.

Comment: Is there a way to alternate the label position so that they go top, bottom, top, bottom ... ? That could help preserve all labels without overlapping.

Comment: An alternative way is to alternate top and bottom labels, rather than removing every other one. To do that I've come up with a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37161022/2005415

Comment: I can't believe how long it took me to find an answer to this seemingly simple question. I love matplotlib/pyplot but its interface is so arcane. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep every third this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 28):

One-liner for those who are into that!

```
n = 7  # Keeps every 7th label
[l.set_visible(False) for (i,l) in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()) if i % n != 0]
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is the better than higher rated answers as it is more flexible. More than every second label can be hidden.

Comment: for those who wish to copy-paste this magnificent one-liner: make sure you've assigned a variable name "ax" to any plot command you have written in your script (e.g. use ax = plt.subplot(); ax.plot(), instead of plt.subplot(); plt.plot())

Comment: I tried other proposed solutions. This worked for me (Python 2.7)

Comment: @Brandon You can also use plt.gca() to get the current axis after doing a plot. I.e. do some plt.plot, then do ax = plt.gca() afterwards. Same goes for the figure, we can use plt.gcf()

Answer (score 17):

Just came across this thread, nice answers. 
I was looking for a way to hide every tick between the nth ticks. And found the enumerate function. So if anyone else is looking for something similar you can do it like this.

```py
for index, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if index % n != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 6):

I use the following to show every 7th x label:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
ax = plt.gca()
temp = ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()
temp = list(set(temp) - set(temp[::7]))
for label in temp:
    label.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

It's pretty flexible, as you can do whatever you want instead of plt.scatter. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For some (mostly beginners) who aren't familiar or comfortable with the object oriented approach for matplotlib, here is a way to hide every 2nd label without needing to use ax:

```python
        plt.plot(Allx,y)
   
        labels = []
        for i in range(len(Allx)): 
            if i % 2 == 0: 
                labels.append(Allx[i])
            else: 
                labels.append("")

         plt.xticks(ticks=Allx,labels=labels)
```