# Matplotlib: strange double-decade axis ticks in log plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels, loglog

I am trying to make a log-log plot that covers many decades in Matplotlib.  However, the default x-axis ticks returned to me are far from ideal as they cover two decades at a time, with only 4 tick marks in between.  The code I am using is the following:

```py
rc('text', usetex=True)
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim([1e26,1e29])
plt.xlim([20,1e10])
plt.xlabel(r'x',fontsize=22)
plt.ylabel(r'y',fontsize=22)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=22,length=9,direction='in')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=22,length=5,direction='in')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(right='on',which='both')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(top='on',which='both')
plt.savefig('example.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

The image returned to me is shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the major x-axis labels go from 10^3 to 10^5, etc.  On the other hand, there are only 4 minor x-axis labels between major labels.  I would like to have major labels every decade, as on the y-axis, with the standard 8 ticks in between each decade.  Moreover, I would ideally like for the labelling on the x-axis to stay as is now, in order for the axis to not be too cluttered.  That is, I want 10^3, 10^5, 10^7, 10^9 to be labeled as they are now.  I just want to extend the major/minor ticks to all decades in between.

Thanks in advance.  Also, if it is helpful, I'm using matplotlib version 2.0.0.  I need to be using this version (instead of an older version) for additional functionality that is only in 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with v2, matplotlib changed to reduce the number of ticks/labels that it draws on logarithmic axes spanning large ranges. The code below shows one way of adding the ticks back.

With this code,

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim([1e26,1e29])
plt.xlim([20,1e10])
plt.xlabel(r'x',fontsize=22)
plt.ylabel(r'y',fontsize=22)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=22,length=9,direction='in')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=22,length=5,direction='in')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(right='on',which='both')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(top='on',which='both')

# manipulate x-axis ticks and labels
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(numticks=15)) #(1)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(LogLocator(numticks=15,subs=np.arange(2,10))) #(2)
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False) #(3)

plt.savefig('example.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

I obtain a major tick every decade, 8 minor ticks in between major ticks, and axis labels for every other major tick. But as I've just made an account to post this answer, I don't have enough reputation to share the corresponding image :(.

Some details on each of the labeled lines (see numbered comments in code above):

1. Increases the maximum number of allowed tick marks. The value 15 is the threshold from v1, see the source code at `matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py`.
2. When the plot axis spans more than 5 decades (undocumented, but see source code), matplotlib v2 defaults to drawing minor ticks at (2,4,6,8) only. This specifies the full range of minor ticks.
3. Turns off every other x-axis label, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341184).