# Increase the distance between xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dataset with 60 dates and values, which I'd like to visualise as a scatterplot.

The space between the individual however is pretty small, resulting in the dates to overlap. I tried rotating them but this didn't really solve my problem. I don't want to change the fontsize either, nor can I omit some labels. I basically want to increase the distance between each label, while keeping them aligned with the actual ticks (in other words: I want to increase the distance between the ticks)

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523710/matplotlib-increase-spacing-between-points-on-x-axis), but it didn't work for me.

```py
day = df["day"].tolist() #a series of dates YYYY-MM-DD (not necessarily consecutive)
median = df[" median"].tolist() #some integers

x = range(len(day))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,median, color='blue')
plt.xticks(x, day, rotation=45, fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you show what it looks like now?

Comment: @NealTitusThomas done!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change spacing between ticks in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863375/how-to-change-spacing-between-ticks-in-matplotlib)

Comment: The space between tick labels is decided by the space between ticks on the axes. The only way to do what you want is to make the axes larger.

Comment: are these "dates" being stored as `datetime64`s or `str`ings?  at a guess they're strings so matplotlib doesn't know what to do with them.  check out [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to increase the width of the plot to fit all the labels nicely without changing the font size and the number of ticks.

Try playing with `plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))` in order to have a width that fit your desires.

More info here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html

Also, try without subplots:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
plt.scatter(x, median, c='blue')
plt.xticks(x, day, rotation=45, fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I already tried increasing the width, but this results in a blank image for some reason.

Comment: That is another problem. Try without subplots as suggested in the last version of the answer. Let me know how it goes, please.

Comment: Also, if you can print out `day` and `median` I can try to plot it on my machine and show you the result.