# There is no plot for matplotlib/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I mentioned the details of what I am trying to plot. My main question has been posted in the last para.

I tried to plot a graph showing time on the x-axis and value on the y-axis. I have six columns in my text file where time is in the 3rd column and value (height or elevation in cm) is in the last column.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv('Area(4).txt',delimiter='\t')
print(df.columns)
```

The file consists of elevations recorded for a month and it includes some unnecessary/missing values which I have filtered below. I want to plot the recordings between 26-30 April. So I did the following

```
df.iloc[[600]]
df.iloc[[695]]

df16=df.iloc[601:696,:]  # this takes the values between 26-29 April
print(df16)

df17=df16[df16.Value!=9999] #filtering of values I don't need
print(df17)
```

After doing all this, the output I require later looks like this:

```
     No    Date              Time    Rand  Col   Value
601  2762  26  4 1991         1:00   231    2    335
603  2764  26  4 1991         3:00   231    4    255
606  2767  26  4 1991         6:00   231    7    185
608  2769  26  4 1991         8:00   231    9    135
609  2770  26  4 1991         9:00   231   10    117
610  2771  26  4 1991        10:00   231   11    125
612  2773  26  4 1991        12:00   232    1    301
613  2774  26  4 1991        13:00   232    2    350
614  2775  26  4 1991        14:00   232    3    370
616  2777  26  4 1991        16:00   232    5    275
618  2779  26  4 1991        18:00   232    7    200
620  2781  26  4 1991        20:00   232    9    140
621  2782  26  4 1991        21:00   232   10    115
622  2783  26  4 1991        22:00   232   11    125
624  2785  27  4 1991         0:00   233    1    315
625  2786  27  4 1991         1:00   233    2    377
627  2788  27  4 1991         3:00   233    4    285
630  2791  27  4 1991         6:00   233    7    210
632  2793  27  4 1991         8:00   233    9    155
633  2794  27  4 1991         9:00   233   10    130
634  2795  27  4 1991        10:00   233   11    113
636  2797  27  4 1991        12:00   234    1    285
638  2799  27  4 1991        14:00   234    3    390
640  2801  27  4 1991        16:00   234    5    325
642  2803  27  4 1991        18:00   234    7    225
644  2805  27  4 1991        20:00   234    9    161
646  2807  27  4 1991        22:00   234   11    115
647  2808  27  4 1991        23:00   234   12    131
648  2809  28  4 1991         0:00   235    1    275
649  2810  28  4 1991         1:00   235    2    390
650  2811  28  4 1991         2:00   235    3    370
651  2812  28  4 1991         3:00   235    4    335
654  2815  28  4 1991         6:00   235    7    255
656  2817  28  4 1991         8:00   235    9    175
658  2819  28  4 1991        10:00   235   11    121
659  2820  28  4 1991        11:00   235   12    125
660  2821  28  4 1991        12:00   236    1    330
662  2823  28  4 1991        14:00   236    3    425
663  2824  28  4 1991        15:00   236    4    422
664  2825  28  4 1991        16:00   236    5    375
666  2827  28  4 1991        18:00   236    7    255
668  2829  28  4 1991        20:00   236    9    175
670  2831  28  4 1991        22:00   236   11    118
671  2832  28  4 1991        23:00   236   12    107
672  2833  29  4 1991         0:00   237    1    245
673  2834  29  4 1991         1:00   237    2    380
674  2835  29  4 1991         2:00   237    3    415
675  2836  29  4 1991         3:00   237    4    375
678  2839  29  4 1991         6:00   237    7    265
680  2841  29  4 1991         8:00   237    9    190
682  2843  29  4 1991        10:00   237   11    122
683  2844  29  4 1991        11:00   237   12    105
684  2845  29  4 1991        12:00   238    1    180
686  2847  29  4 1991        14:00   238    3    415
687  2848  29  4 1991        15:00   238    4    460
688  2849  29  4 1991        16:00   238    5    425
```

But when I tried to plot a graph with **'Time'** on the x-axis and **'Value/Elevation (cm)'** on the y-axis, I don't get a plot at all. The way I tried to plot is probably too simple or wrong but how I can get the plot?
I also want the graph to show that the x-coordinates increment by 6 hours and the y-coordinates to be spaced by 2m.

```
df17.plot(kind='scatter', x='Time', y='Value')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It traced back my recent call and I got an output like 
KeyError: 'Time in hours'

Comment: I think your "csv" file might have some incorrect column delimitation.  I took a subset of your data above and built a test "csv" file.  Making sure the column names were properly tab delimited and the entries in each row were properly tab delimited, I got a graph to display.  When you printed out the columns, did you get output like the following:  Index(['No', 'Date', 'Time', 'Rand', 'Col', 'Value'], dtype='object') ?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Yes, I have a column called "Time". I showed what my text file looks like in my question. It's the third column.

Comment: What's the output of `print(df17.columns.tolist())`

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly  I get this output: ['No', 'Date', '        Time', 'Rand', 'Col', 'Value']

Comment: @NoDakker Would it be possible for you to show you managed to get a graph? If I print the columns I have in my text file, I get this: 
Index(['No', 'Date', '        Time', 'Rand', 'Col', 'Value'], dtype='object')

Comment: KeyErrors in pandas occur when you call a column with a name that's not the "real" name. Typically because of trailing spaces. Just try this: create a new variable `cols = df17.columns.tolist()` and then plot with `df17.plot(kind='scatter', x=cols[2], y=cols[5])`.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Yes, I do get a scatter plot. However, if I understand correctly, I do not want to plot the first column/No as my x-axis. The first column does not mean anything in my dataset. I want to plot the 'Time' column in the x-axis.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Thank you for the KeyError explanation. I tried to use df17.plot(kind='scatter', x=cols[2], y=cols[5] and I get NameError: name 'cols' is not defined.

Comment: First assign `cols = df17.columns.tolist()`

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Yes, thank you. I assigned cols and tried to plot again. However, this appears: ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric. Is this because the time is given as 1:00, 2:00, 3:00? Is there a way to bypass this issue?

Comment: A pandas graph is completed by replacing the spaces in the date column with slashes and combining it with the time column to form a graph. `df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ','/'));df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.cat(df['Time'], sep=' '));df.plot(kind='line',x='DateTime', y='Value')`

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I decided to just do a regular plot and a not a scatter plot. My graph appears but it looks a bit disorganized. For example, my x-axis 'Time' is set like this: 0:00, 16:00, 9:00,1:00, 16:00, 8:00.  Do you know how I can make the customizations so that x-coordinates are spaced by 6 hours and the y-coordinates are spaced by 2m in pandas?

Comment: @r-beginners I want to clarify that the Date column and Time column in my dataset are separate columns and I only want the 'Time' column for my graph. I still tried to run what you suggested to see the output but I got KeyError: 'DateTime'

Comment: My comment is that the date column contains spaces, so replace them with slashes to make it date format. I concatenate the time column with it to make it a DateTime column. I draw a graph in Pandas with that new column as the x-axis. If you need to adjust the time series further, it is easier to use matplotlib to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I am responding to your request in the comments as to how I set up the initial data and then ran your program with a couple of tweaks to adjust to subset of data.

First off, I copied in about twenty-five rows of data from your sample above.  I made sure that the column names were tab-delimited and that each data element in each row was tab-delimited.  This is the data I placed into the file (I named it "Area.txt").

```
No  Date    Time    Rand    Col Value
2762    26  4 1991  1:00    231 2   335
2764    26  4 1991  3:00    231 4   255
2767    26  4 1991  6:00    231 7   185
2769    26  4 1991  8:00    231 9   135
2770    26  4 1991  9:00    231 10  117
2771    26  4 1991  10:00   231 11  125
2773    26  4 1991  12:00   232 1   301
2774    26  4 1991  13:00   232 2   350
2775    26  4 1991  14:00   232 3   370
2777    26  4 1991  16:00   232 5   275
2779    26  4 1991  18:00   232 7   200
2781    26  4 1991  20:00   232 9   140
2782    26  4 1991  21:00   232 10  115
2783    26  4 1991  22:00   232 11  125
2785    27  4 1991  0:00    233 1   315
2786    27  4 1991  1:00    233 2   377
2788    27  4 1991  3:00    233 4   285
2791    27  4 1991  6:00    233 7   210
2793    27  4 1991  8:00    233 9   155
2794    27  4 1991  9:00    233 10  130
2795    27  4 1991  10:00   233 11  113
2797    27  4 1991  12:00   234 1   285
2799    27  4 1991  14:00   234 3   390
2801    27  4 1991  16:00   234 5   325
2803    27  4 1991  18:00   234 7   225
```

Then utilizing your code sample above, I tweaked it to grab the data I placed into the test file (I called it "Area.txt").

```
    import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv('Area.txt',delimiter='\t')
print(df.columns)

df16=df.iloc[0:24,:]  # this takes the values I entered into the "csv" file but should work the same as your range.
print(df16)

df17=df16[df16.Value!=9999] #filtering of values I don't need
print(df17)

df17.plot(kind='scatter', x='Time', y='Value')
plt.show()
```

That yielded the following graph.

[image: Sample Graph]

I guess the point in the terminal output that confirmed that I would generate a graph was the printing of the data frame columns after reading in the data from the "csv" file.

```
Index(['No', 'Date', 'Time', 'Rand', 'Col', 'Value'], dtype='object')
```

So again, because I had a relatively small subset of your data, I could ensure myself that the data was clean.  I hope that helps you troubleshoot your project.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you, I still have some questions. (1) Could you explain to me the part about how you ensured that the column names were tab-delimited and that each data element in each row was tab-delimited? This is the first time I am hearing this so I'm not sure how I am supposed to check this aspect of my text file on my end.

Comment: (2) While I couldn't get a scatter plot, I managed to get a lineplot later on but it looks very messy and hard to understand/interpret. Do you know how I can plot the graph so that x-coordinates are evenly spaced over an interval of 6 hrs like it starts from 12am, then 6am, 12 pm, 6pm,etc and the y-coordinates is evenly spaced by 100 cm?

Comment: The reason I knew that my column names were tab-delimited was that I knew that I had used the tab key when entering in the data.  I don't know what other apps you have but if you have a spreadsheet application that allows the import of csv file data, you might do a test import indicating that the tab key is the delimiter and see if the spreadsheet looks correct.  Regarding comment #2, I am not well versed in that.  However, I found this link [matplotlib spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523710/matplotlib-increase-spacing-between-points-on-x-axis)  that might help.